# Get address of the char

Tags: c++, memory, memory-address

Back then when I was a student, `&obj` was returning the address of the object.
I want to get the address of a simple char and tried all the methods I am aware of:

```
int main()
{
    using std::cout, std::endl;
    char a{ 'x' };
    char* p = &a;
    cout << std::addressof(a) << endl;
    cout << p << endl;
    cout << &a << endl;
}
```

This outputs:

```
x
x
x
```

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong?
How can I get the address of a?

Comment: Just as a guess, pointers have the `<<` operator overloaded to add the value at the address to the stream. Try casting to an `unsigned long` maybe?

Comment: => `static_cast<void*>(p)` etc.

Comment: @KonradRudolph cheers, already read the original post

Comment: Since `<<` found the `x` that the address points to, it looks like you *did* get the address.

Comment: try printf("%p\n", &a);